# Handling Large IF ELIF conditions in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am working with Robot Framework and I have a large condition block that looks like that:

```
Run Keyword If  "car" in '${value}'        Actions.Action A 
...                         arg1=${some_value_1}
...                         arg3=${some_value_2}
...   ELSE IF   "dog" in '${value}'        Actions.Action B 
...                         arg1=${some_value_3}
...                         arg2=${some_value_4}
...   ELSE IF   "parrot" in '${value}'     Actions.Action C 
...                         arg2=${some_value_5}
...                         arg3=${some_value_6}
```

My real condition block is huge and scary (150+ lines) so I am wondering if there's a more elegant and concise way to handle such conditions.

I have tried formatting the whole thing but it still looks ugly. Modyfying func args also didn't lead to a huge success.

Comment: Just a minor hint that the `run keyword if` is obsolete and there is a new, more convenient control syntax exists: `IF - ELSE` [UserGuide](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#if-else-syntax).

Comment: Also, you could use `"dog" in $value` instead of `"dog" in '${value}' `

Comment: Just to clarify, every single "action" gets unique arguments?